# Error finding Android/Java SDKs System error on Visual Studio 2015

Tags: java, android, visual-studio, android-ndk, android-sdk-tools

I tried re-installing Java JDK, Android SDK and Android NDK. Even I re-installed Visual Studio 2015 but the issue is not solved. My SDK has all tools and Android 4.4.2 package. I have shared pictures with links below.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solved that. I try 3 step and which step help for me, i dont understand.

1 - Our Android SDK location change. I transport my desktop and i change source way in Visual Studio.

2 - Computer -> Right Click -> Properties -> Advanced system settings -> Environment Variables -> System variables -> New 
   name : JAVA_HOME value : C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_25 Done.

3 - Our Android NDK location changed.

C:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-ndk-r13b

My problem solved.

Comment: Thanks

```JAVA_HOME value : C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8...```

solved the problem.

Comment: You're welcome. Most likely this step solved my problem.